# Usages of who/which with "best team"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Are both the following sentences correct?

> 1- Hey John don't shout before you win. Let the match begin. You will know **who** the best team in the world **are**.
>
> 2- Hey John don't shout before you win. Let the match begin. You will know **which** the best team in the world **is**.

Answer (score 1):

Both are completely fine in British English. There is a slight difference in meaning, because the first is implicitly referring to the team as a bunch of players, while the second is referring to the team as a unit.

American English tends not to accept the plural verb ("are") with a collective like "team", so I believe many Americans would find the first sentence unacceptable.

Comment: The [American and British English grammatical differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_grammatical_differences#Subject-verb_agreement) page on Wikipedia has a good description of the differences between BrE and AmE treatment of collective nouns.

Comment: For the record, Americans would not necessarily find the usage **unacceptable** and if they did, they are just ignorant, frankly. Most differences with these  types of  issues are really not an issue at all. I doubt a good English teacher (for adolescents) would call it unacceptable. The teacher might point out it is British usage though.